# Set start page in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When I create tabs or sidemenu ionic app I can see in file app.js have

```js
$stateProvider
  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
```

or :

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
```

I want replace start page with login.html file and I tried code:

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
```

and it not run, but when I tried it with :

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
```

it run.

```js
 .state('tab', {
```

and

```js
 .state('app', {
```

what is mean? if I want replace it with

```js
 .state('login', {
```

how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a side menu or a tabs, you need to carry 2 "screens" at the same time, your side menu or your tabs and the "login" in your case. 
If I want to display my menu and other screen, I used liked this:

```
$stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.doacoes', {
      url: '/doacoes',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/doacoes.html'
        }
      }
    });
```

Because AppCtrl is a sidemenu ctrl (in my case) and i also show a "doacoes" html in my screen.